# React app throwing error about key, but I have already assigned a unique key at the top level

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code throwing the error with the console message below:

```
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <h6>Infractions:</h6>
                        {infractions.map(({ id, itype, dateStamp }) => (
                            <li key={id} className="col-12">
                                {itype} {dateStamp}
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </div>
```

and the error

[image]

Comment: It may be because `id` you are getting may not be unique

Comment: The Id is unique, it is generated by uuid

Comment: Could your infractions list can have duplicate infraction ?

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing is because the keys you have set are not unique, or undefined.

From what you have answered in the comments, you are using some kind of UUID to generate said `id` values. Since you haven't included that code in your question, you should probably verify the following:

- The UUIDs you are generating are indeed unique, and you are not accidentally reusing them or setting the same UUID for all records.
- The `id` field is always populated and React doesn't render the list with the values still `undefined`

To check both those suggestions, and any further investigations you may need, you have a variety of tools available.

- You can use `console.log` and output the values to the terminal (it's not the cleanest approach, but it gives quick results)
- You can also show the ID in the component, and see what's going on:

```js
<li key={id} className="col-12">
  (ID: {id}) - {itype} {dateStamp}
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks I got it working - Each ID was fine, and unique.  I had to set up each each each 'infraction' object with empty data first...